# Bound camera to sprite bounds

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a scene camera following a unit (sprite's position), this unit is standing on a terrain sprite, This camera not only follows it, it also zooms in and out using the pinch gesture. Everything works well, except that I want to limit the camera's lower bound to be limited by the lower bound of the terrain sprite. In other words, I don't want the camera to display anything below the terrain sprite. And by this I mean that instead the camera could shift upwards and preserve the scale.

Any swift, obj-c or even pseudo-code answers would help. Thanks!

This is my attempt

```
        let halfTerrain = terrain.size.height/2
        let halfViewport = scene!.size.height/2
        let distanceFromCenter = halfTerrain - cameraPosition.y
        let scaledDistanceFromCenter = distanceFromCenter/cameraScale
        let gapSize = halfViewport - halfTerrain/cameraScale
        let isOverlapping = scaledDistanceFromCenter < halfViewport

        if isOverlapping {
            camera?.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: cameraPosition.x,
                y: -gapSize * cameraScale), duration: movingSpeed))
        } else {
            camera?.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(cameraPosition,
                duration: movingSpeed))
        }
        camera?.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(cameraScale,
            duration: scaleSpeed))
```

Comment: You should include what have you tried so far. That way, you would probably get your answer faster.

Comment: I added what I have tried so far, basically trying to determine the distance from the lower side of the terrain to the lower part of the viewport and shifting clamping the camera y to that value.